# Retrieving Objects From Parse.com

Tags: android, object, nullpointerexception, parse-platform

I am having issued Retrieving objects from Parse.com. I plan to have a list of anywhere from 3 to 25 objects displayed, They will change daily. I will not know the `ObjectID`, or any of the content of the object. I followed [this](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries) guide the best I could.

I wrote this code here to simplify what I am doing. It is throwing a `null pointer exception` in my `.done`.

**UPDATED**

**Saving my object:** //I am doing this successfully

```
            ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
            testObject.put("TheColumn", "The name in the column");
            testObject.saveInBackground();
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
```

**Retrieving my Object**   //Unsuccessfully....

```
          ParseQuery<ParseObject> query  = ParseQuery.getQuery("TestObject");

            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (e==null){

                        Log.d("THE OBJECT", "" +parseObjects.size());


                        name =  parseObjects.toString();
                        Log.d("THE QUERY ", "" + name);

                    } else {
                        Log.d("ERROR:", "" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
```

In my logcat, I get my `Log.d`'s to log. I get two; `D/THE OBJECT: 1` and `D/THE QUERY: [com.parse.ParseObject@XXXXXX]` But if I try to set it to a `TextView`, I get a `nullPointerException`.

Why am I getting data returned like this? I feel I am following [this](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries) guide closely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason for my `nullpointer` was that I was setting the text to a `TextView` in a different class on accident. Got my `r.id`'s confused.